# sync users location with google maps in java script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, navigation, synchronization

Is it possible to synchronize users location using geolocation?, so that if the user is travelling his location will be updated on the page, some what like navigating his location...

i have tried this but, whole map keeps refreshing and takes time to load... It works fine, but, is there a better way that I can keep a track of users location?

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/geolocationmarker-compiled.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map, GeoMarker;

        setInterval (function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 17,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

            GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
            GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed',     function() {
                map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
                alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
            });
            console.log('updating');
            GeoMarker.setMap(map);
        },10000);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
    }

</script>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't recreate the map when the position changes, just update the marker's position on the map.

```
var map, GeoMarker;
function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 17,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
}
setInterval (function() {
    if (!GeoMarker) {
      GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
    }
    GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed',     function() {
            map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
        alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
    });
    console.log('updating');
    GeoMarker.setMap(map);
},10000);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);

if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
}
```